# Python | pydub: how to load wav sample into pydub from np.array instead of a wav file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, wav, pydub

How would I load an audio `np.array` file into PyDub library? Currently, I use `AudioSegment.from_wav(file_path)`, but it is not convenient, if I already have the wav file loaded as a numpy array:

```
sample_rate, wav_sample = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file_path)
```

UPDATE: my wav files are all 16 bit, single channel.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, take this answer with a grain of salt as I don't know `pydub` enough to see if it's working properly, but you should be able to do it from the class initializer providing all the parameters it needs:

```
sample_rate, wav_sample = scipy.io.wavfile.read(file_path) 
segment = AudioSegment(data=wav_sample.tobytes(),
                       sample_width=2,
                       frame_rate=sample_rate, channels=1)
```

It seems to work as it should, assuming a 16bit single channel sample.

Different sample width should be easy to infer from the array size (something like `wav_sample.nbytes() / len(wav_sample)` should do).

Please do some test yourself and let us know!

**EDIT**: multiple channels is a little trickier, `pydub` as far as I can tell wants interwoven channels, while scipy returns them as multiple columns. But it should be easy enough with numpy to reshape the data in the format `pydub` wants, something like the following (**not tested**)?

```
np.vstack((wav_sample[:,0],wav_sample[:,1])).reshape((-1,), order='F')
```